# How to view different questions of a tag in Stack Exchange mobile application?

Tags: support, mobile-web

Is there any way I can read different questions related to One Tag or mix of tags in Stack Exchange mobile application or Web.
Like every time I click next I want to see new question.

Comment: isn't there a "newest" tab already?

Comment: New question by means question I didn't read

Answer (score 1):

Once you click on the "questions", you'll be able to see a screen like below

[image]

In the text area, you can enter your choice of tag and it will update you regarding the new question in *near* real-time.